# 'Bioinformatics' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just reading [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/26311/16521) question regarding the use of deep neural networks for RNA data. I noticed that the user had used the 'biology' tag instead of a 'bioinformatics' tag, so I went to edit their post and saw that there is no 'bioinformatics' tag! I think a 'bioinformatics' tag is much more suitable for such questions than a 'biology' tag: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics
Also, it seems that bioinformatics.stackexchange does not have any good tags for AI questions, so I think this is suitable for us.

Shall we create a 'bioinformatics' tag? (I don't think I have the reputation to do it here on my own.)

Comment: Right now, the description of the tag [tag:biology] seems to cover topics that are not really on-topic here, so, if we also want to keep this tag, we definitely need to clarify which types of questions should be tagged with [tag:biology]. They need to be somehow related to artificial intelligence. I believe people use this tag when there's a question in AI that is somehow related to the biology. For example, [this one](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/9296/2444). However, this may not always be the case, and, in any case, we would still need to clarify the description.

Comment: I also agree with you that [tag:bioinformatics] may be a tag that we can have on the site, but would also need to clarify which questions should be tagged with that and we need to check whether other sites (especially, Stats SE and DS SE) already cover similar questions.

Comment: @nbro Agreed. A lot of the AI/ML methods used in bioinformatics are definitely more statistical in nature (such as PCA, etc.), and so are more suitable for stats.stackexchange. Furthermore, bioinformatics often involves truly huge amounts of data, to the point that it, in the true technical sense, qualifies as "big data"; my understanding is that many of these "big data" data mining methods are more statistical in nature and lean towards being off-topic for ai.stackexchange. However, there are definitely some questions, such as some in DNN, that are probably more suitable for ai.stackexchange.

Comment: Also, I should point out that I'm not very familiar with datascience.stackexchange, so I'm not totally sure of the style of questions they ask there.

Comment: Meanwhile, I changed the description of the [tag:biology] tag to make it more acceptable. The new description is: "For questions related to biology in the context of artificial intelligence. For example, use this tag when you want to ask if a certain machine learning model was inspired by some biological counterpart.".